# why should i include the header file <iostream> after using the namespace std?

Tags: c++, std, header-files, iostream

Since the namespace std already has the c++ libraries that contain the function definitions(if i am right), then why do we include header files on top of it??. Since namespace std includes the c++ standard libraries, I don't see a reason to include the declarations of it separately.

Comment: Not QUITE sure if you are asking "why do we need both namespaces and header files", or "why it makes a difference between order of `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;`?

Comment: You should never include `iostream.h` unless your program requirements include working on DOS.

Comment: saying you are using a namespace is in no way the same as saying you have access to all the classes included in that namespace. So, essentially you are asking why you need to include header files to access the classes that are declared there?

Comment: `iostream.h` looks weird. The current standard refers to [`#include <iostream>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream) actually.

Comment: Why should you? You shouldn't. It would achieve nothing.

Comment: @chris So UNIX programs shouldn't include `iostream`? ;-)

Comment: @CareyGregory: In Unix you probably don't have a `iostream.h` - note the distinction between `iostream` and `iostream.h`.

Comment: @MatsPetersson You don't have it with any version of a Microsoft compiler either (that I know of) other than the headers that come with the WDK, which very few people would have.

Comment: Right, so chris said that "you shouldn't be using it unless you are compiling for DOS", which is exactly what you are saying - it doesn't exist/shouldn't be used, unless you are using a compiler that is for an OS that stopped being used some 15 or so years ago...

Comment: @MatsPetersson I understood what he's saying. I just think the OP used the `.h` by accident, so my comment was a joke. See the smiley?

Comment: _"Since namespace std includes the c++ standard libraries"_ Nope

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you do `#include <iostream>` it causes a set of classes and other things to be included in your source file. For iostream, and most of the standard library headers, they place these things in a namespace named `std`.

So the code for `#include <iostream>` looks something like this:

```
namespace std { 
    class cin  { ... };
    class cout { ... };
    class cerr { ... };
    class clog { ... };
    ...
}
```

So at this point, you could write a program that looks like:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Now, some people feel that `std::cout` is too verbose. So they do:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "hello\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Personally, I'd recommend against this, and if you really feel that `std::cout` is too verbose, then I'd suggest that you use a smaller `using` statement.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

int main() {
    cout << "hello\n";
    return 0;
}
```

If you're wondering why I would recommend against `using namespace std`, then I would forward you to the following two other posts on stackoverflow:

- [C++ Distance Function Keeps Returning -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751478/c-distance-function-keeps-returning-1)
- [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: So " using namespace std; " and then " cout<<"somestring"; " would still refer to the cout in the " <iostream> " file? even without including the <iostream> file? because inside the <iostream> file these cout, cin are placed inside namespace std, so can we just use std namespace and leave out the header inclusion?

Comment: @ManojBharadwaj: No. Many different header files will place things in that namespace. The `using` command doesn't implicitly know which header that is.

Comment: but there is only 1 object by that name inside a single namespace, isn't that enough?

Comment: But how does the compiler know what `cin` is or does? That comes from the content of iostream. The compiler itself does not know what this file contains, or for that matter that `cin` comes from `iostream`. This is part of the runtime library, not the compiler itself, so it must be COMPILED by the compiler for your program to be able to use it.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler itself does not have the definitions of the things that are in any namespace (whether it is `std` or some other namespace). That is the role of source files and header files.

What `using namespace std;` tells the compiler is that "If you can't find some name in the current namespace, go look in the `std` namespace as well".

What `#include <iostream>` tells the compiler is that you want the contents of the header called `iostream` to be included in your sources. This will provide the compiler with code to do `cin`, `cout` and a lot of other related functionality. The content of this file is declared like `namespace std { ... all the stuff goes here ... }`.

The usage of namespace allows someone else, working in `namespace math;` to not have to worry about "Hmm, what do I do now, I need a counter for number of entrances, let's call it `cin` - but hang on, is that ever used anywhere?".

This may not be the greatest of examples, but in large projects, it gets increasingly hard to keep track of things and what names they have. And C++ is a language intended for large projects of millions of lines of code - and now it starts getting hard to remember if you've used a particular name or not. Namespaces make sure that you don't have to worry about it outside of a particular namespace.

(Oh, and in my code, I tend to not use `using namespace std;`, but write `std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;` - this helps to make it clear that the `cout` I'm using here is the `std` one, and not something else. This is particularly useful when you have several namespaces with similar things, like in my own compiler, where I have my compiler with it's functionality, the `std` namespace providing some things, and `llvm` compiler things - if I were to stick `using namespace llvm;` at the beginning of the code, it would be very hard to track whether `Type* p = ...`; is from LLVM or some part of my own code.)

Answer (score 0):

> ...why do we include header files on top of it???

Yes, there is some big confusion here.

### Namespaces

Namespaces are a method to categorize or group together, symbols such as function names.

Namespaces are design to prevent name conflicts between different software components, such as libraries.

Functions that are a part of the standard language, are grouped under the namespace `std`.

The C++ language provides statements to reduce the amount of typing when using namespaces.  One of these is the `using` statement.

### Header (include) Files

When you write a program, the compiler is not required to automatically include *all* the symbol definitions, such a function declarations.  You need to tell it which functions you plan on using.

For example, I could write a program without using the `sort` or `advance` functions from the `algorithm` group.  Therefore I would not include the header file `algorithm`.

The C++ language is designed to be "use what you need", in other words, we can create small programs by only including the functions we need.

### Other Platforms

By the way, there are many other platforms out there than the one you are using.

Some platforms need to fit in small memory areas and may not have a keyboard or display (such as embedded controllers).

So remember, C++ was defined to support platforms from the small and constrained to the large and virtually unconstrained system.

Thus the requirement to "include only what you need" theme.

### Summary

In summary, since the C++ languages doesn't automatically, magically, provide the definitions of the entire library, including the template library, you need to tell the compiler which groups of functions you want to use.  This allows for quicker compilations since only the required header files are specified.

*Note*: Some shops and library supplies like to use the *Monolith* include system.  This means that they have one include file that includes their entire library, whether you use one function or many.  The `windows.h` is a classic example.  One detriment is that when one header file is changed, everything needs to be rebuilt.  With separated include files, only the components that include the changed header file need to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

Use of preprocessor directive #include is as old as c++ itself. And its not going away any sooner.In C++ namespace Doesn't import anything into your program, it just defines the scope of your particular header file's function.So, both are required. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29590111/4599070)to understand why use namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is: `namespace std` has all the definitions of functions/classes of `iostream` library. So simply using `using namespace std` is enough to call or use `cout` or all other functionalities of `iostream` library. Why do we have to use line `#include <iostream>`? It seems redundant.

Roughly we can think that `iostream` library has two files: header and implementation/source file. These two files have a namespace called `std`. The header file only contains the declarations or forward declarations of classes or functions or variables that `iostream` library is going to use and these declarations or forward declarations are under the `std` namespace. The implementation file contains the actual implementations of the classes or functions or variables and these implementations are under the `std` namespace; this file is also called the source file.

So if you only use `using namespace std` without `#include <iostream>` in your `main.cpp` file compiler will search `std` namespace in your `main.cpp` file, but it is not here. You will get compiler error.

Now if you include this `#include <iostream>` line in your `main.cpp`, preprocessor will go `iostream`'s header file and copy the `std` namespace along with its code into our `main.cpp`. And linker will link the precompiled(as `iostream` is a SLT so it comes with compiler with prebuilt) source/implementation file of `iostream` to your `main.cpp`. Now to use functions or variables of `iostream` that sit under `std` namespace in `main.cpp` we have to use scope resolution operator(::) to tell the compiler that `cout`, `cin` and other functionalities of `iostream` sit at `std` namespace. Thus we simply write like this: `std::cin`, and `std::cout`.

Now typing `std::` seems redundant to some people so they tell the compiler by using this `using namespace std` "Hey compiler, if you don't find any variables/functions/classes in global/current namespace go look in the `std` namespace." Though this is not the best practice but that is another topic to discuss. Therefore your assumption that `std` namespace contains all the definitions of all SLT's functions/classes/variables of C++ is not correct in most cases, but `std` namespace only contains the declaration from STL is the correct assumption.

Here is a dummy implementation how `iostream` libray is added to our code files:
`iostream.h`:

```
// This is header file that only contains the
// functions declarations.
namespace std_dum
{
    int add(int x, int y);

    int mult(int x, int y);
}
```

`iostream_dum.cpp`:

```
// This is source file of iostream_dum.h header
// which contains the implementation of functions.

#include "iostream_dum.h"

namespace std_dum
{

    int add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    int mult(int x, int y)
    {
        return x * y; 
    }

}
```

`main.cpp` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "iostream_dum.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << std_dum::add(100, 200) << '\n';
    std::cout << std_dum::mult(100, 200) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

To see what happens to our `main.cpp` file after preprocessing run this command: `g++ -E main.cpp iostream_dum.cpp`.

Here is roughly our `main.cpp` looks like:

```
namespace std_dum
{
    int add(int x, int y);

    int mult(int x, int y);
}

int main()
{
 std::cout << std_dum::add(100, 200) << '\n';
 std::cout << std_dum::mult(100, 200) << '\n';

 return 0;
}

namespace std_dum
{

    int add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    int mult(int x, int y)
    {
        return x * y;
    }

 }
```

For the sake of clarity, I discarded all the codes that the preprocessor copied from `#include <iostream>`.

Now it should be pretty clear.